# Type Error Cannot read property 'push'

Tags: node.js, push

** How to fix : Type Error Cannot read property 'push' of undefined **

[image]

Comment: please put the relevant code into the question instead of hosted on an external site.

Comment: You have a lot of errors in your code If you want to post the actual code instead of an image of the code, I will help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo in `getStudens()` (*note: this function name appears to be missing the 't' in 'students'*) which is resulting in an undefined variable being returned.  Since `student` is undefined, you'll get an error invoking any functions on it (eg. `push()`)

There is no 'r' in `undefined`.

```
var students = storage.getItemSync('students');
if (typeof students==="underfined") {
    return [];
}
else students;
```

I suspect you also need to change the `else students;` to `return students;` to cover the case where the array is defined.

Here is a modified version of the relevant code which should work.

```
function getStudents() {
    var students = storage.getItemSync('students');
    if (typeof students==="undefined") {
        return [];
    }
    return students;
}

function addStudents(studentId, studentName) {
    var students = getStudents();
    students.push({
                   id: studentId, 
                   fullname: studentName
    });
    storage.setItemSync('students', students);
}
```

Comment: Jason , thank you . i fixed like you but i'm so sorry , it's still don't run

Comment: @EcoHoàng Without at least knowing what error you are encountering, it's difficult for me to offer further suggestions.  If you update your question with your current code & error, I'll try to help.